# Run webapp in background even when smartphone screen is turned off

Tags: javascript, web-applications, smartphone

Is there a possibility to run a webapp (pure HTML and JavaScript) in background continuing its work (e.g. audio, vibration, ajax) for all plattforms? Even when the screen is turned off?

I found a related question with no accepted answer [background HTML5 WebApps on Android 2.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331245/background-html5-webapps-on-android-2-3) but that doesn't help. Is the only way to achieve that to convert it to a native app?

Comment: In the meantime ServiceWorkers appeared and may provide something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible with just only JavaScript. With [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), you can install PhoneGap plugin into your app (mobile app) and can start the background service by consuming Native API (Android or iOS etc.) But this is not for web app but for mobile app.

Comment: Mhm. I'm afraid so. Despite that there _is_ the possibility to continue audio playback when running in background - but only on IOS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4841563/622041