# How to prevent automatic screen lock for a mobile website on android and iphone

Tags: android, ios, locking, screen, sleep

I've build a mobile web app with PHP, HTML and JS. (The app is not native and not in the Apple iPhone App Store or Google Android Play Store).

In my mobile app I use jPlayer (https://jplayer.org/) for users to listen to sound meditations. The duration is around 20 minutes for each meditation. The problem is that the screen goes automatic in lock or sleep mode.

On some Android devices is 10 minutes the maximum for the automatic lock. So they can not relex and listen to the full sound without reactivating the screen.

I tried to use the javascript lib NoSleep.js (https://richtr.github.io/NoSleep.js/) and tested it on my iPhone 12. It is not working, the screen locks anyway.

Is there some way to keep the screen active?

Update: I found out that the sound keeps playing when I use the mobile website application in the browser Chrome or Safari. But when I save the app as a desktop icon and then use the jPlayer it stops after screenlock. Probably there is no solution for this.

Comment: A web site cannot prevent the screen from locking. This would be a security risk.

Comment: Do you want the app to run in safari or as a stand-alone "web app" icon. The former can continue playing audio in the background. A web app cannot. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557991/ios-background-audio-in-a-web-app

Comment: @Paulw11 could you elaborate on how the risk would be different from a native app doing it? Native apps can do it, so why not the browser (Web-app) ?

Comment: Because there is a level of trust that comes with apps due to them being reviewed by Apple and scanned, while not perfect, this is a very different case to a user opening a web site.  They would not expect browsing to a web site to prevent their phone from sleeping/locking.  There are also issues with battery drain

Comment: I also came here to find an answer, but could not find one. I am not sure about this, but I found https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-keep-your-screen-awake-using-javascript which provides a solution that might work.